# Adding custom action when blueprint.rest=true in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I only have blueprint.rest = true. All others are disabled. I like the rest=true because it restricts the GET/POST/PUT appropriately for find/update/destroy/create.

But I would like to add another action in the controller which would do be something like

PUT /mycontroller/:id/validate

Comment: See the [route config](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Configuration/Routes.html) and expanded [route docs](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Routes) on the Sails beta site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this static route in the `config/routes.js` file.

> "PUT /yourcontroller/:id/validate" : {
>
> ```
>  controller : 'YourController',
>  action: 'yourAction',
>  }
> ```

Comment: This is a fine answer, but I'm not sure what you mean by your comment about "blueprints for this controller/action won't be called".  This custom route won't affect the default blueprint routes (find, create, update, destroy) for "YourController" at all.